# Encoding strangeness with Cp500 (LF & NEL)

Tags: java, encoding, byte, java-6, codepages

Recently I had a strange issue with the Cp500 (EBCDIC) encoding during a transformation from bytes to String and then back from String to bytes.

The issue is that one specific character [LINE FEED - LF - 0x25](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?file=cp500.kte&char=25) is, during this transformation, being transformed to this character [NEW LINE - NEL - 0x15](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?file=cp500.kte&char=15).

Here the following code that validates this :

```
byte[] b25 = { 0x25 };
byte[] b4E = { 0x4E };

System.out.printf("\n0x25 in hex : <0x%02X>", b25[0]);
System.out.printf("\n0x4E in hex : <0x%02X>", b4E[0]);

String stringB25 = new String(b25, "Cp500");
String stringB4E = new String(b4E, "Cp500");

System.out.printf("\nOther way, 0x25 in hex : <0x%02X>", stringB25.getBytes("Cp500")[0]);
System.out.printf("\nOther way, 0x4E in hex : <0x%02X>", stringB4E.getBytes("Cp500")[0]);
```

Output :

```
0x25 in hex : <0x25>
0x4E in hex : <0x4E>
Other way, 0x25 in hex : <0x15>
Other way, 0x4E in hex : <0x4E>
```

In order to understand this behavior, I gave a look into the [IBM500.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/nio/cs/ext/IBM500.java) class, and I see that both 0x15 and 0x25 characters *maps* to the "\n" character.

What's the reason behind that?

Ultimately, is there a way to preserve the bytes input consistency between String encoding and decoding *mechanism*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    transcode();
    System.setProperty("ibm.swapLF", "true");
    transcode();
  }

  private static void transcode() {
    byte EBCDIC_NL = 0x15; //next line
    byte EBCDIC_LF = 0x25; //line feed
    byte EBCDIC_CR = 0x0D; //carriage return

    ebcdicToUtf16(EBCDIC_NL);
    ebcdicToUtf16(EBCDIC_LF);
    ebcdicToUtf16(EBCDIC_CR);

    utf16ToEbcdic("\u0085"); //next line
    utf16ToEbcdic("\n"); //line feed
    utf16ToEbcdic("\r"); //carriage return
  }

  private static void ebcdicToUtf16(byte... b) {
    String utf16 = new String(b, Charset.forName("IBM500"));
    System.out.format("%02x -> %04x%n", b[0] & 0xFF, utf16.charAt(0) & 0xFFFF);
  }

  private static void utf16ToEbcdic(String s) {
    byte[] b = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("IBM500"));
    System.out.format("%04x -> %02x%n", s.charAt(0) & 0xFFFF, b[0] & 0xFF);
  }
```

When run on an IBM JVM (1.7) this will emit:

```
15 -> 000a
25 -> 000a
0d -> 000d
0085 -> 15
000a -> 15
000d -> 0d
15 -> 000a
25 -> 000a
0d -> 000d
0085 -> 15
000a -> 25
000d -> 0d
```

[This IBM JVM patch SI23602](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas36a46c090c815e0078625716c00528125) explains:

> ADDITIONAL BACKGROUND:  There are two standards in the industry for
>   EBCDIC handling of the newline function.  The two standards are to use
>   the LF (0x25) CDRA or NL (0x15) MVS open edition. Early versions of
>   Java (up through JDK 1.3) are inconsistent in their use of the newline
>   function with most EBCDIC encodings using the 0x15, while some others
>   used the 0x25.   IBM JDKs, beginning in JDK 1.4, have chosen to
>   standardize all EBCDIC character encodings on the use of NL (0x15).
>
> To address the dual standard being used for the newline function, this
>   APAR will provide a switch that allows certain EBCDIC converters to
>   swap between use of 0x15 or 0x25 as the newline function.  The default
>   behavior for all EBCDIC character encodings will remain to map the
>   unicode \u000A character to EBCDIC 0x15 character.  Specifying the
>   java property `"ibm.swapLF=true"` will cause the converters to switch
>   its mapping of unicode \u000A to EBCDIC 0x25.  The converters which
>   support this java property as a switch are:  Cp284, Cp285, Cp500,
>   Cp1140, Cp1141, Cp1142, Cp1143, Cp1144, Cp1145, Cp1146, Cp1147,
>   Cp1148, Cp1149.

Neither setting will map anything to U+0085 (the [assigned Unicode value for NL/NEL](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)). Presumably this is for historical reasons - ASCII does not have a NEL character and EBCDIC-to-ASCII must have been relatively common.

It would be possible to implement a loss-less roundtrip to a Unicode encoding but it is unlikely that the [commonly available encoders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) will do this.

Notes:

- Sun/Oracle JVMs will not honor the *ibm.swapLF* system property.
- [Unicode newline-function guidelines](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr13/) don't explain NL-to-LF mappings but are otherwise informative

Comment: Very well explained. ibm.swapLF works like a charm when using IBM JDK.