# Decoding EBCDIC byte array to String and back to byte array

Tags: java, encoding, decoding, ebcdic

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962074/decoding-array-of-hexadecimal-bytes-to-a-specific-codepage-brings-a-wrong-result/), I pointed out the following problem:

```java
        byte[] a = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25 };
        String stringValue = new String(a, "273");
        int firstResult = ByteBuffer.wrap(a).getInt();
        System.out.println("First Integer Result: "+firstResult);

        byte[] valueEncoded = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringValue.getBytes("273"), 0, 4);            
        
        System.out.println("Hex valueEncoded:");
        for (byte b : valueEncoded){ System.out.format("0x%x ", b); }   
        int finalResult = ByteBuffer.wrap(valueEncoded).getInt();
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        System.out.println("Final Integer Result: "+finalResult);
```

This results in:

```
First Integer Result: 37
Hex valueEncoded:
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x15 
Final Integer Result: 21
```

My expected result is 37, but the finalResult is 21. I got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962074/decoding-array-of-hexadecimal-bytes-to-a-specific-codepage-brings-a-wrong-result/#67962178) with an explanation why this is the case:

> bytes to string: EBCDIC 0x25 -> UTF-16 0x000A string to bytes: UTF-16
> 0x000A -> EBCDIC 0x15
>
> 0x000A is the standard line terminator on many systems, but it's
> generally output as "move to beginning of next line". Converting to
> IBM 273 is 'probably' because the text is destined for output on a
> device that uses that code page, and perhaps such devices want NL
> rather than LF for starting a new line.

**My question is:**

Can I somehow code a workaround in order to get the expected result while still using Strings (UTF-16) and decoding/encoding back and forth?
As mentioned in my previous post this is needed since we persist (Strings) to an DB2 table which then will be read by an IBM machine.

I was digging through several stackoverflow questions but could not find a solution to my problem:
[Encoding strangeness with Cp500 (LF & NEL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633276/encoding-strangeness-with-cp500-lf-nel/24703995#24703995)
This answer is recommending the system property `ibm.swapLF` but this not an option for me since I use `OpenJDK 1.8.0_292-b10` and not any IBM JDK. Besides that my codepage is not supported by this property.

EDIT: I did some loggers, hope it helps.

Comment: `.....and back to byte array` You are not doing that. Further your code does not start with a byte array but with a string. Better start with your array.

Comment: Please log all values. Starting with the value of stringValue. Show us what happens. Update your code here with the logs and tell the output. Log valueEncoded in hex.

Comment: well, I construct a String by using a new byte[], so I start with an array. what do you think I do instead?
you cannot really log stringValue, I mean by using System.out.println(stringValue); you will not be able to see anything. the log will be empty since it is decoded in IBM273 which is not readable by humans.

Comment: On the first line of your code you should define that array. Then at the second line use it in the string. Then when you are done you would have converted it back to a byte array (see subject of your post) and you could compare them. But .. you are not converting back to a byte array . I said that before.. And if you use an Android Java String you could log it and tell us the result.

Comment: 0x25==37 dec...

Comment: Well that array is defined when I construct as mentioned. I don´t see a big difference by defining that array in the first line and then constructing the String. It will not fix my problem for sure and basically it´s the very same as posted by me. And I do convert back to a byte array (see byte[] valueEncoded). And this question is about Java, not Android. Most likely no big difference, but I have no experience in Anroid... And I don´t understand what you are trying to say by "0x25==37 dec" since I already mentioned that I expect 37 (which implicitly says 0x25==37) but the result is 21.

Comment: `do convert back to a byte array (see byte[] valueEncoded).` Well but you did not tell us which hex values in that array. And i dont see you logging them. Please tell those values. And sorry for Android, slip of the mind .. And please tell us that you are converting a byte array to an integer with a lot of intermediate steps..

Comment: Ok I see your point, I just updated the code with some loggers

Comment: And to your point regarding converting byte / int: at the very end I need a String cause I have to persist to a DB which uses CP237, it´s mentioned in my question

Comment: You added some logging indeed. But you did not tell us what was logged. We still do not know the hex values in valueEncoded.

Comment: You could just run my code ;-) Ok edited still. So any idea?

Comment: So already in valueEncoded: the value is 0x15. Then why did you post code after determining valueEncoded? The following code looks irrelevant to me then i would say that 0x15 stays 0x15. So where is it that you wonder why that integer has value 0x15? Can you also tell us (as you did not do that) which values you had expected in valuesEncoded?

Comment: I would advise against using **java strings**, Use byte arrays and convert it to/from D2 using bytes or Hex string `INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE COL1 VALUES(X'00000025')`